# Button Value to EditText Logic - Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, logic, calculator

What is the logic of adding text to an edittext when button is pressed. Like in simple calculator, when u press a button the numbers will be shown to the edittext. What do you call that logic? I need a developers explanation.

Comment: @Hariharan I need an explanation, not a code. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: There is no logic in it. what do you really expect? Thats simply an `onclick` event.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai ofcourse there is. evry simple code you use logic.

Comment: @jandroid what logic calculate the numbers and while clicking button print it.

Comment: I'd suggest using a textview with a background and have a grid with number buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        edittext.setText("text");

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I need an explanation, not a code. Please read my question carefully. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Simply,to each and every button press, append the number to edittext regarding the pressed button.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `append()` of the `EditText`. The Argument will be appended at the end of the Editable.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   editText1.append("your string to add at the end.");
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the other term for append?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is get the text from button and set it to the edittext,in aappending mode

Comment: what is the other term for append?

Comment: there is two way for appending one is directly using append function or use settext method